# functools.reduce in Python not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, functools

I would like to sum across keys of dictionaries nested within a list using the `functools.reduce` function

I can accomplish this WITHOUT the `functools.reduce` function with the following simple program:

```
dict1 = {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
dict2 = {'a': '5', 'b': '0'}
dict3 = {'a': '7', 'b': '3'}

data_list = [dict1, dict2, dict3]

total_a = 0
total_b = 0
for record in data_list:
    total_a += eval(record['a'])
    total_b += eval(record['b'])

print(total_a)
print(total_b)
```

As I said however, I would like to produce the same results using the `functools.reduce` method instead.

Here is my attempt at using `functools.reduce` with a lambda expression:

```
from functools import reduce

dict1 = {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
dict2 = {'a': '5', 'b': '0'}
dict3 = {'a': '7', 'b': '3'}

data_list = [dict1, dict2, dict3]

total_a = reduce(lambda x, y: int(x['a']) + int(y['a']),data_list)
total_b = reduce(lambda x, y: int(x['b']) + int(y['b']),data_list )

print(total_a)
print(total_b)
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error and do not know why:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Does someone know why I am getting this error?

Comment: What's the purpose of calling `eval('1')`? It's function misuse, to convert string to int use `int()`.

Comment: why are you using `reduce()`?

Comment: @OlvinRoght Since the '1' is stored as a string, I believe I have to convert it to an integer before I can use it with the `+` operator to sum over all of the values

Comment: @deadshot It seems like it is something that would work since the `data_list` data_list is an iterable and so was hoping I could use it for this use-case

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I just edited my post and replaced 'eval' with 'int' -- I get the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

> Does someone know why I am getting this error?

First, let's reduce (pun intended) the sample to a minimum:

```py
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> data = [{"a": 1}, {"a": 2}, {"a": 3}]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x["a"] + y["a"], data)   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Same error. But observe this:

```py
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x["a"] + y["a"], data[:2])   
3
```

That's working. So what's going on? For simplification, let's assign the lambda expression to a variable:

```
f = lambda x, y: x['a'] + y['a']
```

Reduce combines the input like this:

```py
# Example: reduce(lambda x, y: x["a"] + y["a"], data[:2])   
>>> f(data[0], data[1])

# which evaluates in steps like this:

>>> data[0]["a"] + data[1]["a"]
>>> 1 + 2
>>> 3
```

But what's happening when reducing the full list? This evaluates to

```py
# Example: reduce(lambda x, y: x["a"] + y["a"], data)   
>>> f(f(data[0], data[1]), data[2])

# which evaluates in steps like this:

>>> f(data[0]["a"] + data[1]["a"], data[2])
>>> f(1 + 2, data[2])
>>> f(3, data[2])
>>> 3["a"] + data[2]["a"]
```

So this errors out because it tries to access item `"a"` from the integer 3.

Basically: The output of the function passed to reduce must be acceptable as its first parameter. In your example, the lambda expects a dictionary as its first parameter and returns an integer.

Comment: I like how you provided the details of each step -- that really helped me understand what is going on.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reduction function receives the current reduced value plus the next iterated item to be reduced. The trick is in choosing what that reduction value looks like. In your case, if you choose a 2 item list holding the reduced values of 'a' and 'b', then the reduction function just adds the next 'a' and 'b' to those values. The reduction is most easily written as a couple of statements so should be moved from an anonymous lambda to a regular function. Start with an initializer of `[0, 0]` to hold the reduced 'a' and 'b', and you get:

```
from functools import reduce

def reducer(accum, next_dict):
    print(accum, next_dict) # debug trace
    accum[0] += int(next_dict['a'])
    accum[1] += int(next_dict['b'])
    return accum

dict1 = {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
dict2 = {'a': '5', 'b': '0'}
dict3 = {'a': '7', 'b': '3'}

data_list = [dict1, dict2, dict3]

total_a, total_b = reduce(reducer, data_list, [0, 0])
```

Comment: i didn't think to be able to sum multiple 'keys' at once -- neat trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand how `reduce()` works. In the function passed to it, its first argument is a partial result *so* far, and has nothing directly to do with the iterable passed to `reduce()`. The iterable is passed one element at a time, to the function's second argument. Since you want a sum, the initial value of the "partial result" needs to be 0, which also needs to be passed to `reduce()`.

So, in all, these lines will print what you want:

```py
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x + int(y['a']), data_list, 0))
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x + int(y['b']), data_list, 0))
```

EDIT: replaced `eval()` with `int()` above, so it matches the edited question. It's irrelevant to the answer, though.

EDIT 2: you keep changing the question, but I'm not going to keep changing the answer to match ;-) The code just above fully answers an earlier version of the question, and nothing *material* has changed. Exactly the same things are still at work, and exactly the same kind of approach is needed.

### Gloss on types

While Python doesn't require explicit type declarations, sometimes they can be helpful.

If you have an iterable delivering objects of type `A`, and the result of `reduce()` is of type `B`, then the signature of the the first argument passed to `reduce()` must be

```
def reduction_function(x: B, y: A) -> B
```

In the example, `A` is `dict` and `B` is `int`. Passing a dict for both can't possibly work. That's essentially why we need to specifiy an initial value of type `B` (`int`) in this case.

In doc examples, `A` and `B` are typically *both* `int` or `float`. Then a simple + or * is already type-correct for `reduce()`'s first argument.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, `eval()` should be `int()`

Comment: Ya, ya, I changed it - but it's irrelevant to the OP's actual question ;-)

Comment: Imho, if it's sum then it should be solved using `sum()`, even in functional style `sum(map(int, map(itemgetter('a'), data_list)))`

Comment: I agree, but that's also irrelevant to the OP's actual question :-)

Comment: @TimPeters thanks for the explanation.  in the [functools.reduce docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce), the example shows the case where an initial value is NOT provided, in which case, the first element of the iterable is used.  why would that not apply in my case? meaning, for `total_a`, why would the initial value not automatically be set to 1? (the value for key 'a' in `dict1`)

Comment: In the doc example, the type of the result is exactly the same as the type of the iterable's elements, so `reduce()` can _start_ by combining the first two elements. But in your case, the result is of type `int`, and the elements are of type `str`. The int returned by your function from adding the first two dict values can **not** be used as the first argument for the second attempt: `int' object is not subscriptable`. So you need to start it off with something that works instead.

Comment: @TimPeters I like how you fixed the problem by passing an initial value matching the output of the function. That approach did not occur to me.

Comment: @Bluehorn, I think it was surprising to me too at first - but that was something like 25 years ago, and in the meantime I may have forgotten that it's not obvious ;-)

Comment: @HumanityFirst, I'll note too that the implementation gets more complicated if it wanted to make a special case of the first function call. That's ugly. In real life, it's actually not a burden to tell `reduce()` what it needs to know up front.

Comment: See edit at bottom for more about types.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're adding integers, an alternative to `reduce` is `sum`:

```py
data_list = [{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}, {'a': '5', 'b': '0'}, {'a': '7', 'b': '3'}]

total_a, total_b = map(sum, zip(*((int(d['a']),int(d['b'])) for d in data_list)))

print(total_a, total_b)
# 13 5
```